# Serializing and deserializing complex objects

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am trying to serialize and deserialize a list of objects. First I generate the list:

```
var groups = db.AssetGroupList.ToList();

foreach(var group in groups)
{
   group.AssetSubGroupList = db.AssetSubGroupList.Where(p => p.AssetGroupId == group.AssetGroupId).ToList();
   foreach(var subGroup in group.AssetSubGroupList)
   {
      subGroup.AssetList = db.AssetList.Where(p => p.AssetSubGroupId == subGroup.AssetSubGroupId).ToList();                  
      foreach(var asset in subGroup.AssetList)
      {
         asset.ReportAsset = null;// db.ReportAssetList.Where(p => p.AssetId == asset.AssetId).FirstOrDefault();
      }
   }
}
```

Then I serialize it and deserialize it:

```
var json_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var json = json_serializer.Serialize(groups);
List<AssetGroup> routes_list =(List<AssetGroup>)json_serializer.DeserializeObject(json);
```

However I get following error:
System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[CopyToCosmosDB.AssetGroup]'.'

I have following models:

```
[Table("AssetGroup")]
public class AssetGroup
{
    [Key]
    public int AssetGroupId { get; set; }

    public int Code { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public List<AssetSubGroup> AssetSubGroupList { get; set; }
}


public class AssetSubGroup
{
    [Key]
    public int AssetSubGroupId { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("AssetSubGroupList")]
    public int AssetGroupId { get; set; }

    public int Code { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public List<Asset> AssetList { get; set; }
   }

[Table("Asset")]
public class Asset
{
    [Key]
     public int AssetId { get; set; }

    public int Code { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int AssetSubGroupId { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public ReportAsset ReportAsset { get; set; }
}

[Table("ReportAsset")]
public class ReportAsset
{
    [Key]
    public int ReportAssetId { get; set; }
    public decimal Rating { get; set; }
    public int ReportId { get; set; }


    public int AssetId { get; set; }
    public string Remark { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Updated { get; set; }

    //public Asset Asset { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Try an array instead of a List<> : AssetGroup[] routes_list =(AssetGroup[])json_serializer.DeserializeObject(json);

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Almost same error message: System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[]' to type 'CopyToCosmosDB.AssetGroup[]'.'

Comment: Does it work with 'var' with no casting?

Comment: It does, but then nothing is typed and all properties are represented as key/value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Ohh dear. Seemed there is another method Deserialize that does the task, and not DeserializeObject:

```
var json_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var json = json_serializer.Serialize(report);
Report routes_list =(Report)json_serializer.Deserialize<Report>(json);
```

Thanks for your help.